# How to assign tab order from left to right - winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form in C# project that keeps some information. I created a bunch of textbox and combobox dynamically, depend upon user input.

So here there is two rows since user has given the input as 2. All the components in the image are dynamically created. For each component i have created a class to set the property and its behaviour.

Now the issue is I need to traverse the component using tab.

When i tried to set tabindex = 1 for the first textbox and tabindex = 2 for the second textbox. I'm traversing the components vertically like mentioned below

**Actual Output :** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aILu7.png)

The code in which i have added are following.

```
        public class addDynamicCptboxComponents : add_components
                {
                    public override void add_dynamic_components(int getNoOfTxtBox, int pointX, int pointY, Form1 f)
                    {
                        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                        f.panel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
                        txtBox.Location = new Point(pointX, pointY);
                        txtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
                        f.panel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
                        txtBox.Name = "Add_txtBox" + getNoOfTxtBox;
//assigned the tabindex as 2 for the second textbox 
                        txtBox.TabIndex = 2;
                    }
                }

                public class addDynamicDateofServiceComponents : add_components
                {
                    public override void add_dynamic_components(int getNoOfTxtBox, int pointX, int pointY, Form1 f)
                    {
                        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                        f.panel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
                        txtBox.Location = new Point(pointX, pointY);
                        txtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
                        f.panel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
                        txtBox.Name = "Add_dos_txtBox" + getNoOfTxtBox;

    //assigned the tabindex as 1 for first textbox 
      txtBox.TabIndex = 1;
                    }
                }
```

But what i need is , I need to traverse the components horizontally as mentioned below.

**Expected Ouput:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnros.png)

**The Requried tab order is specified in the above image.**

Comment: Hard-coding the TabIndex does not look healthy.  This invariably ends better if you create a UserControl.  Or a new panel inside panel1.  With a new container, the TabIndex starts back at 0.

Comment: Hans makes a good comment about having a usercontrol or panel that represents the set of controls you're inserting.  If you don't want to do that, then how about your add method takes a "rowindex" input, and you make the tab indexes rowindex*controlsperrow + 1 or 2 as per your current plan.  Then all of row0 will have numbers smaller than all of row1 etc.

Comment: @SazooCat thanks for your idea. It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the name of your class you are adding rows dynamically to your form. But since you are hard coding the tab index the result per row looks like in your expected output. This means by tabbing you go from index 1 to index 1 to index 2 to index 2 and so on and so forth.

I'd advise you to have an incrementing tab index stored somewhere in your application which is incremented after it is assigned to a new dynamically created control.

As a really simple example I created a fresh forms project which just has two buttons. The first one adds a new textbox and the second button switches into a new row. And in this example everything has the tab index you require. The code behind looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int currentX = 0;
    private int currentY = 0;
    private const int tbWidth = 75;
    private const int tbHeight = 23;
    private int currentTabIndex = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBoxOne = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(textBoxOne);
        textBoxOne.Location = new Point(this.currentX, this.currentY);
        textBoxOne.Size = new Size(tbWidth, tbHeight);
        textBoxOne.TabIndex = currentTabIndex;
        textBoxOne.Text = $"{currentTabIndex}";

        currentTabIndex++;

        this.currentX += tbWidth + 5;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentY += tbHeight + 5;
        currentX = 0;
    }
}
```

Please bare in mind this is just a simple example. I could help you better in the context of your application if I knew more about it.

Comment: @zelenka Thanks for the effort, your answer and user Sazoocat comment gave the spark to solve the issue.